# Flask SocketIO not sending messages to assigned room

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm building an app in which each user joins an specific room linked to an id shared with other users (let's say one admin is connected individually to many users but those users are only connected to that admin). I need to do this automatically, so when they signup I do a automatic assignment at, for example, join.html:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
   socket.emit('connected');
});
```

Which calls this:

```
@socketio.on('connected')
def connected():
    global user_unique_room_id
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        rol = current_user.get_current_user_role()
        ...
        if rol == 'User':
            user_current_room = str(current_user.shared_id) + str(user_unique_room_id)
            join_room(user_current_room)
            models.User(id=current_user.id).update(
                    set__room = user_current_room)
            user_unique_room_id += 1
```

I'm storing the room so when they send a message they know exactly where to emit it:

```
@routes.route('/new_message', methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def new_message():
        room = current_user.room
        socketio.emit('new_message', data, room=room)
        return jsonify(data), 202
```

But this is not working. And because if I do this...

```
socketio.emit('new_message', data, room=None)
```

...it acually sends the message, I feel like `join_room` at `@socketio.on('connected')` is not assigning the room correctly and just probably assigning it to None.

To clarify, the `current_user.shared_id` is something like `5f0c30c6593bfe9ecb6fdab3`.
And the `user_current_room` is something like:

```
5f0c30c6593bfe9ecb6fdab30
5f0c30c6593bfe9ecb6fdab31
5f0c30c6593bfe9ecb6fdab32
...
5f0c30c6593bfe9ecb6fdab399
```

Just in case it helps, this is how my User model looks like:

```
{'email': 'example@example.com', 'password': example, 'username': 'example', 'shared_id': 
'5f0c8f74315aa1ebe80b50a2', 'room': '5f0c8f74315aa1ebe80b50a20', 'timestamp': 
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 9, 52, 17, 322000), 'active': True, 'id': 
ObjectId('5f0d80511d1cbebeec44980b'), 'role': 'User'}
```

I'm new to SocketIO so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something incorrectly, but I just don't know what.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: In your POST route, you've used `room = current_user.room` but in your model, the room is stored in `current_room`.

Comment: Sorry, that was me changing the name of some attributes now to make my question easier to read. Just edited it!

Comment: Add `logger=True` to your `SocketIO()` class to have additional debug logs sent to the terminal. That can help you identify if the messages are going to the room you expect or somewhere else.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks so much! Just did that and got this:

```received event "connected" from 95145f972df9480d82a3dc80d44bb073 [/]``` then 

```95145f972df9480d82a3dc80d44bb073 is entering room 5f0c8f74315aa1ebe80b50a20 [/]``` then 

```emitting event "new_message" to 5f0c8f74315aa1ebe80b50a20 [/]```

So it seems like it's doing it correctly - not getting the message though... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe enable logging in the browser to see if the message is arriving?